# Bundler: How can I bundle install from outside the ruby app directory?

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

### Attempt 1: Installation from outside ruby app directory

Fresh Vagrant install and it doesn’t work:

```
$ bundle install --path=/var/ruby/test/ --gemfile=/var/ruby/test/Gemfile

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Using bundler 1.16.3
Fetching daemons 1.2.6
Installing daemons 1.2.6
Fetching eventmachine 1.2.7
Installing eventmachine 1.2.7 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/ruby/test/ruby/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180805-18844-1r8x9rm.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ssl-dir
    --without-ssl-dir
    --with-ssl-include
    --without-ssl-include=${ssl-dir}/include
    --with-ssl-lib
    --without-ssl-lib=${ssl-dir}/lib
    --with-openssl-config
    --without-openssl-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an
executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:657:in `try_ldflags'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1813:in `pkg_config'
    from extconf.rb:65:in `pkg_config_wrapper'
    from extconf.rb:92:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/ruby/test/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/ruby/test/ruby/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/ruby/test/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  thin was resolved to 1.7.2, which depends on
    eventmachine
```

### Attempt 2: Installation from app directory

Fresh Vagrant installation, and it works!

```
$ cd /var/ruby/test/
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 1.16.3
Fetching daemons 1.2.6
Installing daemons 1.2.6
Fetching eventmachine 1.2.7
Installing eventmachine 1.2.7 with native extensions
Fetching mustermann 1.0.2
Installing mustermann 1.0.2
Fetching rack 2.0.5
Installing rack 2.0.5
Fetching rack-protection 2.0.3
Installing rack-protection 2.0.3
Fetching tilt 2.0.8
Installing tilt 2.0.8
Fetching sinatra 2.0.3
Installing sinatra 2.0.3
Fetching thin 1.7.2
Installing thin 1.7.2 with native extensions
Bundle complete! 2 Gemfile dependencies, 9 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

### Question

**How can I `bundle install` from outside the ruby app directory?**

### Environment:

Single-user rvm installation on CentOS 7 Vagrant box:

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 9 18:05:47 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ rpm -qa | grep openssl
openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64
openssl-devel-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64
openssl-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64

$ rvm list
=* ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

## UPDATE 1

Contents of `eventmachine-1.2.7/mkmf.log`:

```
$ cat /var/ruby/test/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/mkmf.log
# I ADDED NEWLINES FOR READABILITY – THIS WAS A ONE-LINE STRING WHEN OUTPUT TO THE CONSOLE:
"gcc -o conftest
-I/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-linux 
-I/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward 
-I/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. 
-O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter 
-Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers 
-Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement 
-Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat 
-fPIC conftest.c -L.
-L/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib -Wl,-R/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib -L.
-fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic
-Wl,-rpath,'/../lib' -Wl,-R'/../lib' -lruby -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

| pkg-config --libs openssl
=> "-lssl -lcrypto  \n"
```

**Note:** I also had the [same exact issue when trying to install the `puma` gem](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1625); the installation would fail when puma started installation "with native extensions". At first, I thought it was puma, but now I believe it’s a bundler (perhaps rvm?) issue.

## UPDATE 2

Contents of `gem_make.out`:

```
$ cat /var/ruby/test/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/gem_make.out
current directory: /var/ruby/test/ruby/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180806-22205-1cnr9v9.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ssl-dir
    --without-ssl-dir
    --with-ssl-include
    --without-ssl-include=${ssl-dir}/include
    --with-ssl-lib
    --without-ssl-lib=${ssl-dir}/lib
    --with-openssl-config
    --without-openssl-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:657:in `try_ldflags'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1813:in `pkg_config'
    from extconf.rb:65:in `pkg_config_wrapper'
    from extconf.rb:92:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/ruby/test/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

I did find [this related issue comment](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1281#issuecomment-306101007), which motivated me to do this:

```
sudo yum install -y ruby-devel

# … and then:
$ rpm -qa | grep ruby
ruby-libs-2.0.0.648-33.el7_4.x86_64
rubygem-psych-2.0.0-33.el7_4.x86_64
rubygem-rdoc-4.0.0-33.el7_4.noarch
ruby-irb-2.0.0.648-33.el7_4.noarch
rubygem-json-1.7.7-33.el7_4.x86_64
rubygem-io-console-0.4.2-33.el7_4.x86_64
ruby-2.0.0.648-33.el7_4.x86_64
ruby-devel-2.0.0.648-33.el7_4.x86_64
rubygem-bigdecimal-1.2.0-33.el7_4.x86_64
rubygems-2.0.14.1-33.el7_4.noarch

# … and then:
$ bundle install --path=/var/ruby/test/ --gemfile=/var/ruby/test/Gemfile
```

Yet I still get the same error:

```
Installing eventmachine 1.2.7 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Comment: What does /var/ruby/test/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/mkmf.log say? Your clues to the failure should be in that file.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Casper, I really appreciate it! I updated my question with the contents of `mkmf.log`. I don’t understand what it’s trying to tell me.

Comment: And what about /var/ruby/test/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/gem_make.out ? The problem is I've yet to see an actual error message. Something failed, but so far we've only seen secondary messages. The primary message needs to be found somewhere.

Comment: Are you running bundler as root? You're installing into a system location.

Comment: Great questions! Thanks you for the help! I am not running bundler as root; I’m trying to avoid root unless necessary; could it be as simple as running `sudo bundle exec ...`? But if this is the case, why does `bundle exec ...` work when ran in the app’s root (using the default vagrant user)? I will post contents of `gem_make.out` here shortly. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Updated question with contents of `gem_make.out`.

Comment: The vagrant user has write permissions to /var/ruby/test?

Comment: Anyway. This is a mystery. I am unable to replicate this problem on my own server, and the errors make no sense. You may have stumbled upon a bundler bug, but it's hard to say, because the error messages do not tell us what the problem is. You just have to use the second method for now. At least you have one solution that works.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks so much for your help Casper, I greatly appreciate you taking the time to take a look and give tips/advice. Have an excellent day!