# Cannot install json gem on Mac

Tags: ruby, xcode, rubygems

I'm not able to install json gem on my M1 MacBook. This is the command I'm running.

```
sudo gem install json -v '2.6.2'
```

This is the error I'm getting. I'm guessing it because it's picking up Xcode 14.1 Beta 3, but I'm not sure how to have it use a different version of Xcode or if that's the problem.

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.6.2/ext/json/ext/generator
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20221018-37799-1wcwkww.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.6.2/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.6.2/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
In file included from ./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: note: did not find header 'config.h' in framework 'ruby' (loaded from '/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks')
1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/json-2.6.2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is:

1. Assuming you're trying to install a modern 2.x version of JSON, this error is because [it can't see the ruby development tools](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/error-occurred-while-installing-bundle-install-and-gem-install-json/262596).
2. This is because MacOS doesn't include ruby development tools for its base-level version of ruby. That version of ruby is used for some very core-level things on Mac and they lock it down pretty intensely.
3. The solution is to use `rbenv` to install a new, user-controlled copy of ruby. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66087121/1060526) has a good step-by-step of how to do that, but the TLDR; is get `brew`, run `brew install rbenv ruby-build`, and then run `rbenv install 2.6.10 && rbenv global 2.6.10 && rbenv rehash`. Then restart your terminal.
4. Now `gem install` commands should target the copy of ruby you just installed. (You can validate this by running `ruby --version` and making sure it lists the version you installed in step 3.) This should fix your issue installing json, whether via `gem install` or `bundle install`.

Comment: I get the error after other gems have installed.

Answer (score 0):

resolved by CocoaPods/CocoaPods#10286
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
close and reopen terminal
rvm install ruby@latest
rvm use ruby-3.0.0 --default

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

These steps helped me https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35836#issuecomment-1397633782

> Note for this post. Don't use sudo to install any dependencies
>
> I unistalling all, literally... And install all again winthout
> sudo!!!!
>
> after 7 days... my problem was permissions because i installed some
> dependencies with sudo and any rubys versions and etc......
>
> delete all cache or folders, and start of zero inside of opt/homebrew
> erease all
>
> now go your folder now use cmd + shift + .
>
> your see hide folders delete all... caution this! delete only what you
> are sure are remnants of a bad installation of the environment
>
> try install all again winthout sudo
>
> homebrew watchman node (lts) Zulu11 (Java) cocoa pods gem
>
> Only in my .zshrc path envrioments Rbenv, homebrew gem (see docs)
>
> My OS
>
> macOS 13.1 Ventura Apple Silicon M2 Tools of Xode 14.x (lts)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by linking

> brew link --overwrite ruby

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This issue was already reported here, https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/4462.
Can you try `bundle update && bundle install`.
`bundle update` will install all of your dependencies, but if you dont want to update all dependencies, try `bundle update json` only.

Comment: This issue is from 5 years ago and appears to be different from the current problem. As OP notes, they are having problems with `sudo gem install` and not bundler.